# How to get list of sheets id(s) from specific SpreadSheet with Google Sheets API?

Tags: api, google-sheets

i can put data in the cell,
i can CopyTo to make new sheet from existing sheet.

but when i want to delete several sheets, i need list of sheet id(s)

but i don't know how to get the list of sheet id(s) from speadsheet?

does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: I understand that you want to retrieve sheet IDs in the spreadsheet using spreadsheet ID. Is this correct? If it's correct, you can retrieve sheet IDs using ``spreadsheets.get`` of Sheet API v4. The query parameter for retrieving sheet IDs is ``fields=sheets(properties(sheetId,title))''. You can see the detail information at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

Comment: If you need a sample script, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 2):

The following function will display all sheet names and id's for the active spreadsheet.

```
function getSheetId()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var ids=[];
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    ids[allSheets[i].getName()]=allSheets[i].getSheetId();
  }
  var s='<table width="100%">';
  for(key in ids)
  {
      s+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Sheet Name</strong></td><td>%s</td><td><strong>Sheet Id</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>',key,ids[key]);
  }
  s+='</table>'
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(800).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Sheet Keys for Spreadsheet: ' + ss.getName())
}
```