# How to write a list of Sheet Names and ID's to an existing sheet, instead of html

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

A number of my Google Sheets have so many tabs that it takes time to find the tab I am looking for and Google Sheets does not provide a way to "search" for a tab. I have therefore been looking for a Google Apps Script that will automatically capture all Sheet Names and then create clickable links to each sheet. This would make navigation to the tabs much faster.

I recently found an Apps Script which collects all the sheet names and sheet id's, and with info it's simple enough to setup a formula that generates a url and the job will be done.

The only downside is that this script writes the output to an html page, instead of writing it to an existing sheet (e.g. SheetLinks)

Could somebody please assist, by re-writing the last few lines of the script such that it writes the output to a Sheet called SheetLinks.

Here is the Script:

```
function getSheetId()
    {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
    var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
    var ids=[];
    for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
    {
      ids[allSheets[i].getName()]=allSheets[i].getSheetId();
    }
    var s='<table width="100%">';
    for(key in ids)
    {
      s+=Utilities.formatString('<tr><td><strong>Sheet Name</strong></td><td>%s</td><td><strong>Sheet    Id</strong></td><td>%s</td></tr>',key,ids[key]);
    }
    s+='</table>'
    var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(800).setHeight(450);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Sheet Keys for Spreadsheet: ' + ss.getName())
}
```

Link to script source: [How to get list of sheets id(s) from specific SpreadSheet with Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45749835/how-to-get-list-of-sheets-ids-from-specific-spreadsheet-with-google-sheets-api?newreg=d12d3c9a12d148e0a91966a9e1f83ab0)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Create a 2 d array [[col1row1,col2rrow1],[col1row2,col2row2],...] col1 is names and col2 is ids. Then us setValues to post them into the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

To create a list of clickable links to the sheets, you need something like this:

```
function listSheetURLs() {

  // Get the active spreadsheet and all its sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  var values = [];
  
  // Loop through all the sheets and create an array with the sheet name
  // Embed the URL in the name of the sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheetName = allSheets[i].getName();
    // The sheet ID is used to create the url
    var sheetId = allSheets[i].getSheetId();
    var url = ss.getUrl() + '#gid=' + sheetId;
    values.push(['=HYPERLINK("' + url + '", "' + sheetName + '")']);
  }
  
  // Get the SheetLinks sheet or create it if it doesn't exist, then clear its contents
  var sheetLinks = ss.getSheetByName("SheetLinks");
  if (sheetLinks) {
    sheetLinks.clear();
  } else {
    sheetLinks = ss.insertSheet("SheetLinks");
  }
  
  // Write the array to the SheetLinks sheet and set the first column as a name with hyperlink
  sheetLinks.getRange(1, 1, values.length, 1).setValues(values);

  // Display an alert to confirm that the Sheet Keys have been added to the SheetLinks sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Sheet Keys have been added to the SheetLinks sheet.');
}
```